# How to add rows to datagridview winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to add rows to a `datagridview`. I tried a lot of possibilities, but it doesn't appear anything on it. I think the best solution is to create a datatable, and then to use it as datasource for my gridview. I use winforms. Please, any other idea is welcomed . This is what I have tried so far:

```
public DataTable GetResultsTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Name".ToString());
        table.Columns.Add("Color".ToString());
        DataRow dr;
        dr = table.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Mike";
        dr["Color "] = "blue";
        table.AcceptChanges();
        return table;
    }
public void gridview()
{
     datagridview1.DataSource=null;
     datagridview1.DataSource=table;
}
```

Comment: I rarely do WinForms, but if you're going to assign a `DataSource` don't you also have to bind it?

Comment: I think on winforms you don;t have to bind it. Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose ? Have you defined any columns in the datagridview Adding rows is just abt like `gridview.Rows.Add(n)` for n rows or `gridview.Rows.Add()`

Comment: are getting data from database for `gridview`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i found two mistake in your code:

1. `dr["Color "] = "blue";` Column Color should without space  `dr["Color"] = "blue";`
2. You forgot to add row to the table

   `table.Rows.Add(dr);`

you can try this

```
public DataTable GetResultsTable()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Name".ToString());
    table.Columns.Add("Color".ToString());
    DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
    dr["Name"] = "Mike";
    dr["Color"] = "blue";
    table.Rows.Add(dr);
    return table;
}
public void gridview()
{          
    datagridview1.DataSource =  GetResultsTable();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways , but in different conditions.

As my following code shows you gridview.add method in case of string array:

```
datagridview1.Rows.Add( { val, val, val });
```

It depends upon context and situation at which you want to apply it.

Answer (score 3):

Try This method:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col1", "Name"); // "Col1" is the name of the column and  "Name" is the column header text"
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Col2", "Age");
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("ABC", "25");
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();

DataTable table = new DataTable();

dgv.DataSource = table;

table.Columns.Add("Name");
table.Columns.Add("Color");
table.Rows.Add("Mike", "blue");
table.Rows.Add("Pat", "yellow");

this.Controls.Add(dgv);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But also,it doesn't appear anything on my gridview. I can't explain why...