# Progmatically adding row to grid with backcolor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I was previously using a listview and the below would add a row to the listview while settings it's backcolor:

```
string[] row = { Number, Type, Name };
var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
listViewItem.BackColor = Color.Green;
myListView.Items.Add(listViewItem);
```

Is there something similar for a grid? At the moment, all I've got is:

```
string[] row = { Number, Type, Name };
myGrid.Rows.Add(row);
```

**This is note a duplicate**: This question is about setting the color of a row at the time of adding it due to a condition not shown on the grid, and **not** needing to loop through an existing grid and set the color based on a value inside the grid.

Comment: Please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965043/how-to-add-rows-to-datagridview-winforms.

Comment: @Christos

Nice way of adding data to a grid but I don't see where it addressed setting background color?

Comment: @SteveWellens I'm looking to set the background color when adding a row, that question is iterating through a grid and changing color depending on a condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string[] row = { Number, Type, Name };
int rowPosition = myGrid.Rows.Add(row);
myGrid.Rows[rowPosition].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

The `Add` method returns the index of the added row and you can use it to set the `BackColor` property of `DefaultCellStyle`.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank-you. The reason why iterating through the array afterwards wouldn't work easily is because the color is set depending on a value that isn't shown in the grid.