# How to add new row on click winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a winforms application that I am developing, I have hit a dead end. What I am trying to do is on each "click", add a new row to my `DataTable` with the values input in the form. This `Datatable` is the DataSource for my `DataGridView`. Can someone point me in the right direction on how this can be achieved.

Articles I looked at:

[How to add new row to datatable gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965043/how-to-add-rows-to-datagridview-winforms)

My code:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        //inserting into order table
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string articleId = cmbArticle.Text;
        string productDescription = txtDesc.Text;
        string type = txtType.Text;
        string materialType = txtMaterial.Text;
        string size = cmbSizes.Text;
        string quantity = txtQuantity.Text;

        try
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Article");
            dt.Columns.Add("Description");
            dt.Columns.Add("Type");
            dt.Columns.Add("Material");
            dt.Columns.Add("Size");
            dt.Columns.Add("Quantity");
            dt.Columns.Add("DateTime");

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                //addrows
                dr["Article"] = articleId;
                dr["Description"] = productDescription;
                dr["type"] = type;
                dr["Material"] = materialType;
                dr["Size"] = size;
                dr["Quantity"] = quantity;

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dgvView.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain how you code isn't working?  What *exactly* is going wrong?

Comment: The problem is, when I click on add it adds a row to the datatable which is fine. But if i click on add again to add different information it just overwrite the existing row? I want to be able to add new rows...

Comment: The code you posted add a single row to a new DataTable. I mean that you are allocating a new datatable each time the click event is raised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On each click you are creating a new `DataTable` which would be with just one row, You need to create `DataTable` once and then just keep adding rows to in the click. Define your `DataTable` at class level and then in your event just add a new row to it.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //at class level
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateDataTableColumns();
    //.... your code
}
```

Then have a  method to create table structure, call that method **once** from your `From_Load` event.

```
private void CreateDataTableColumns()
{
    dt.Columns.Add("Article");
    dt.Columns.Add("Description");
    dt.Columns.Add("Type");
    dt.Columns.Add("Material");
    dt.Columns.Add("Size");
    dt.Columns.Add("Quantity");
    dt.Columns.Add("DateTime");
}
```

Later add rows to your class level `DataTable` in `Add` event.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string articleId = cmbArticle.Text;
    string productDescription = txtDesc.Text;
    string type = txtType.Text;
    string materialType = txtMaterial.Text;
    string size = cmbSizes.Text;
    string quantity = txtQuantity.Text;

    try
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        //addrows
        dr["Article"] = articleId;
        dr["Description"] = productDescription;
        dr["type"] = type;
        dr["Material"] = materialType;
        dr["Size"] = size;
        dr["Quantity"] = quantity;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dgvView.DataSource = dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

*(I believe you are doing something with the exception object in your catch block, like logging, showing message to user etc)*

Comment: Thank you @habib, I realise my two mistakes. Firstly datatable was being created each time like you pointed out, and secondly to create the columns separately.