# Datagrid view show its values in GUI on header click?winform

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, datagridview, datagrid

i have a GUI problem when i assign datatable as datasource on formload, then onlick button i populate datatabel and its rows shown in grid view but GUI issue is that as shown in image row appear in graphical format only when i change the position of form of click on grid header or move row then all row appears other wise they are not shown see code

on load form

```
   private void WebScrapingApp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { datatable1.Columns.Add("catagory", typeof(System.String));
        datatable1.Columns.Add("PageNo", typeof(System.String));
        datatable1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(System.String));
        datatable1.Columns.Add("price", typeof(System.String));
        datatable1.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(System.String));
        datatable1.Columns.Add("Location", typeof(System.String));
        dataGridView2.DataSource = datatable1;
        this.dataGridView2.Update();
    }
```

then onlclick call a fucntion that have loop to ADD rows

```
            for (int i = 3; i <= 41; i++)
                     {
                         try
                         {

   datatable1.Rows.Add(s, pageIndex.ToString(), tmpNames, tmpLocations, tmtimes, tmprices);
                             this.dataGridView2.Update();
                             datatable1.AcceptChanges();

                 }
       }
```

**PROBLEM**: as shown in image populated data become visible on click of header row, as first coloumn is still invisible in grid when you click its header it will appear

IMAGE FOR GRAPHICS IS BELOW LINK

[IMAGE OF PROBLEM SOME PART CLICK ME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOb7H.png)

Comment: what do you want to say ? Is header row disappearing on button click ?

Comment: no onclick they appear

Comment: ok so what is the problem ?

Comment: when i click header the they below data become visible other vise data populate but not appears what is this issue i faced it many times , only on header click below data become visible as image shows first column is still not visible but when i click the top header it will appear

Comment: I can not see the image due to internet security privacy . So you want to say that you first click on button then nothing happens , then you click the header then the data becomes visible ? is it ?

Comment: yes code runs and populate grid but its data become visible only when header click or form position changed

Comment: ok I suggested you an answer , try it

Comment: no same problem there

Comment: see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Update this Button Click Code :

```
   for (int i = 3; i <= 41; i++)
      {
          try
            {

  datatable1.Rows.Add(s, pageIndex.ToString(), tmpNames, tmpLocations, tmtimes, tmprices);
  datatable1.AcceptChanges();   
  dataGridView2.DataSource = datatable1;               
  this.dataGridView2.Update();


          }
      }
```

Or try the following approach :

Create a method to Bind the Grid :

```
 public void BindResultsTable()
    {
           datatable1=null;
            datatable1.Columns.Add("catagory", typeof(System.String));
            datatable1.Columns.Add("PageNo", typeof(System.String));
            datatable1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(System.String));
            datatable1.Columns.Add("price", typeof(System.String));
            datatable1.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(System.String));
            datatable1.Columns.Add("Location", typeof(System.String));


          for (int i = 3; i <= 41; i++)
          {
              try
                {

      datatable1.Rows.Add(s, pageIndex.ToString(), tmpNames, tmpLocations, tmtimes, tmprices);
      datatable1.AcceptChanges();   


              }
          }
      dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
      dataGridView2.DataSource = datatable1;               
      this.dataGridView2.Update();
    }
```

Call this function on button click event :

```
        BindResultsTable();
```

Visit this also :

[How to add rows to datagridview winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965043/how-to-add-rows-to-datagridview-winforms)